# Double check my quantifier logic? $(\exists x~:~P(x) \rightarrow \exists y~:~Q(y)) \equiv (\exists z~:~P(z) \rightarrow Q(z))$

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I was looking at some random math problem and needed to resolve

$$\bigg( \exists x ~:~ P(x) \bigg) \rightarrow \bigg(\exists y ~:~ Q(y) \bigg) \tag 1$$

by rewriting as an equivalent statement.  I came to the conclusion:

> $$\bigg( \exists x ~:~ P(x) \rightarrow \exists y ~:~ Q(y) \bigg) \equiv \bigg(\exists z ~:~ P(z) \rightarrow Q(z) \bigg) \tag 2$$

which is what I would like double checked.

I did so by dividing the universe into 4 disjoint (some possibly empty) sets:
$$\begin{align} 
E_3 &= \{x ~:~ P(x) \land Q(x) \} \\
E_2 &= \{x ~:~ P(x) \land \lnot Q(x) \} \\
E_1 &= \{x ~:~ \lnot P(x) \land Q(x) \} \\
E_0 &= \{x ~:~ \lnot P(x) \land \lnot Q(x) \} \\
\end{align}$$

If $E_2$ is the only nonempty set, then **(1)** cannot be satisfied.  Otherwise, any element of any other set provides witness to $x$ and $y$ in **(1)**.  So I get:

$$\begin{align}
\bigg( \exists x ~:~ P(x) \rightarrow \exists y ~:~ Q(y) \bigg) 
&\equiv \bigg(E_3 \ne \emptyset \lor E_1 \ne \emptyset \lor E_0 \ne \emptyset\bigg) \\
&\equiv \bigg(\exists z ~:~ \lnot(P(z) \land \lnot Q(z))\bigg) \\
&\equiv \bigg(\exists z ~:~ P(z) \rightarrow Q(z)\bigg)
\end{align}$$

Seems right to me.  Can't think of any counter examples.  Maybe there is a more direct proof that doesn't involve set comprehension?  Any feedback is appreciated.  Tag this not-homework.

Comment: What are the weird dots for? Do they take the place of brackets? Doex $\exists z:P(z)\rightarrow Q(z)$ mean $\exists z[P(z)\rightarrow Q(z)]$?

Comment: add brackets instead of dots.  do you mean: $\exists x (Px \to (\exists y Qy)) $ or $ (\exists  x Px) \to  (\exists  y Qy) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In (2), we have $\Rightarrow$ but not $\Leftarrow$.  Example to show that $\Leftarrow$ fails: $P(x)$ is "$x=1$" and $Q(y)$ is always false.  Then the RHS of (2) is true (take $z=0$) but the LHS is false.

Comment: Thanks! I see my mistake now.